# Rich Text Content Control is deleted when table is edited

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to create a C# add in for Microsoft Word 2007 in Visual Studio 2008.  The add in is supposed to create a table within a rich text content control such that at a later time the add an can re-reference that table in order to edit it.  I have successfully been able create the table inside of the content control and re-reference the content control to change the table contents.  Unfortuately, after doing so the content control is removed for some reason and therefore I would be unable to reference the table again.

Here is the code that creates the table and content control:

```
    private String name = "Hello";

    private void btnTest1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.RichTextContentControl richTextControl1;

        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application == null)
            return;

        Document vstoDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.GetVstoObject();
        object start = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Start;
        object end = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.End;
        object Unknown = Type.Missing;

        Word.Range thisrange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(ref start, ref end);
        Word.Table oTable = vstoDoc.Tables.Add(thisrange, 2, 2,ref Unknown, ref Unknown);

        oTable.Select();
        richTextControl1 = vstoDoc.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl(name);
        richTextControl1.Title = "Control " + name;

        name += " again";
    }
```

Here is the code that references the content control and ends up deleting it:

```
    private void btnTest2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.RichTextContentControl richTextControl1;
        Word.Table oTable;

        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application == null)
            return;

        Document vstoDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.GetVstoObject();
        object Unknown = Type.Missing;

        Word.ContentControls controls = vstoDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Control Hello");
        foreach (Word.ContentControl control in controls)
        {
            oTable = control.Range.Tables[1];
            oTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Testing";
        }
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I found 1, maybe 2, possible work arounds.  The first is to simply create a new content control around the table everytime you edit it and give it the same title with a new, unique name.  The other work around would be to not use content controls and track the tables by their index.  This would require some custom listener to fire an event when a new table is created without the add in and would be quite sensitive in other ways too.  Neither of these workarounds are as pretty as I would like them to be.

Comment: What about creating a bookmark at oTable.Range and using its name to locate the table (in VBA you can use the bookmark name aas an index to the bookmark collection but in C# it's possible that you have to iterate the collection to find it). OTOH you may have similar problems with bookmarks being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the LockContentControl attribute of the control to true, or whatever is required in C#.

Comment: Unfortunatly that does't work, it throws an exception when I try to edit the table, saying that the control is protected.  I tried editing the contents of the table by hand and had no problem doing that so I'm assuming the error was thrown as it was trying to delete the content control again.